# Clean way to parse ldap query results

Tags: php, active-directory, explode

I am parsing the results of an ldap call to an active directory.  I am trying to get all users in a security group.  Here are my results:

```
    $res =    [member] => Array
            (
                [count] => 2
                [0] => CN=User 1,OU=SomeOU,DC=someDC,DC= someDC2
                [1] => CN=User 2,OU=SomeOU,DC= someDC,DC= someDC2
            )
```

Is there a cleaner way to get the name of out the results? (i.e. User 1,User 2)

```
         foreach ($res['member'] as $k => $v){
             $exp = explode("=",$v);
             $exp = explode(",",$exp[1]);
             $name = $exp[0];
             echo $name."\n";
         }
```

Comment: Maybe [ldap_explode_dn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-explode-dn.php) or any of it's siblings.

Comment: Did any of the provided solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that it's more clear way to do this, but you can use `preg_match` function.

```
foreach($member as $key => $value) {
    $matches = [];
    if (preg_match('/^CN=(.*?),OU/', $member, $matches)) {
        echo "$matches[1]\n";
    }
}
```